# How should I index a book in Solr?

Tags: solr, indexing, full-text-search

I have a PDF file of the book I want to index but I want to be able to tell which chapter(and even the sentence) the word came from in the book. How can I do that in Solr as I'm not sure the correct way to go about this from the docs. How would I do it if it weren't a PDF file but a text file for a book?

Comment: Hum, are you asking about the index-routine - how to extract that information from PDF - or about the schema design?

Comment: Well for extracting from the PDF that would be http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler I think. I'm asking how in example/exampledocs it is adding all those documents, how would I go about doing it for a book with different chapters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that easily with PDFs. If you have access to ePub versions, you job would be a lot simpler.

PDF (unless it has accessibility layer) does not preserve the text flow, so you will have real problem determining text itself, never mind the chapters, etc.

The problem is not with Solr (yet), but with basic content extraction from PDF. Look at Apache Tika and see how much information it can extract. If that's not enough, you need to use something other than PDF.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. If I have just text(just changing the pdf to text), would that be better? I also do have the ePub versions too but I dislike that some of format of the text (their use of double quotes, dashes and elipses are odd and screw up my searches).

Comment: If you have just plain text, how would the algorithm know what your chapters/headings are? I'd try epub first, perhaps normalizing the double quotes and other issues you hit.

Comment: Ah thanks that is an obvious answer(normalizing) now. For plain text though how would I handle solr knowing what is a chapter?

Comment: How would YOU know it's a chapter? You need to feed Solr the documents at the level of granularity you want to find. If it's a sentence, your **document** is a sentence. If it's a chapter, your **document** is a chapter. So, it's up to you how you split it; Solr does not provide any magic for that part. Though, you may want to look into parent/child block-indexing for some advanced possibilities with chapter/sentence grouping/searching.